# How to convert time to specific timezone in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function that is supposed to take in a specific time (entered into the database as UTC) and output a readable 12-hour format time in the user's timezone. The user sets their timezone upon signup. This is the function:

```
def format_time(time_string)
    return time_string.to_time.in_time_zone(@org_info.timezone).strftime("%-l:%M %p")
end
```

This is where:

```
@org_info = Org.where(username: session[:username]).first
```

As you can see I am trying to use the helper function in_time_zone but it doesn't change the time outputted at all. How can I display these times correctly?

Comment: I would use the I18n.localize method; i wrote a blog post on rails and timezones that you might want to read? http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time can be parsed from string as per current time zone using Time.zone.parse

```
Time.zone.parse(time_string)
```

But You need to set the required timezone before as below:

```
Time.zone = 'Mumbai'
```

After setting up the timezone all the parsing will be done in that time zone.

I you need to have different timezone for different users then set specific timezone for user in before_filter in ApplicationController.
eg:
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone # here the time_zone method should return the timezone name for current_user

Now wherever you want to display time in the user timezone simply call in_time_zone method on time object.
eg:

```
2.0.0-p353 :003 > Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0xa3a75a0 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=nil> 
2.0.0-p353 :004 > time = Time.zone.parse('15/02/2014 10:05 AM')
 => Sat, 15 Feb 2014 10:05:00 UTC +00:00 
2.0.0-p353 :005 > Time.zone = 'Mumbai'
 => "Mumbai" 
2.0.0-p353 :006 > time = Time.zone.parse('15/02/2014 10:05 AM')
 => Sat, 15 Feb 2014 10:05:00 IST +05:30
```